# How to delete rows of table in data browser of Parse(Parse.com) programatically in objective c from xcode

Tags: objective-c, database, xcode, chat, parse-platform

I am developing chat application in `objective c` in XCode. So when chat message count reaches 100 then i want to delete `rows` of `table` in `database` of parse.com. So how can i do this programatically? From code i am using `PFQuery` object to insert `data` as below.

```
 // Initialize parse query with classname 'chatroom'
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:className];

chatData  = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:Sender,receiver,nil];

// set query to retrieve table data which contain specific senderId and recieverId from parse table 'chatroom'
[query whereKey:SET_SENDER containedIn:array];
[query whereKey:SET_RECEIVER containedIn:array];
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Deleting objects: https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#objects-deleting/iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using deleteInBackground property to delete record from Parse Table.

eg. 
  deleteObjectId is defined Parse object.

```
[deleteObjectId deleteInBackground];
```